# SQL detecting changes in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my database

Events

```
Date,Time,EventCode
1/1/2020, 7AM, F
1/2/2020, 8AM, N
1/3/2020, 9AM, S
1/4/2020, 9AM, L
1/6/2020, 9AM, Z
```

I am learning how to write a query that can detect when the EventCode changed from N to any value after N. We don't care about values prior to N.

The date is provided because my query needs a start date and end date.
Therefore if I am searching for data that occurred from 1/3/2020 to 1/6/2020, we would have NO data to report because there was no initial EventCode of N present.

However if we modified the query to  1/2/2020 to 1/3/2020, we would get 2 rows. The first row (which is the row containing the EventCode N) and the row immediately after.

Will be using SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019

Example Dataset

```
ID                                     EventType EventDateTime
103917  C   2021-07-16 10:21:18.513
103921  C   2021-07-16 10:49:04.050
103921  C   2021-07-16 12:44:46.320
103921  C   2021-07-16 12:44:46.327
103921  C   2021-07-16 12:44:46.333
103921  C   2021-07-16 12:44:46.340
103921  C   2021-07-16 12:44:46.347
103921  C   2021-07-16 12:44:46.353
103921  N   2021-07-16 12:45:35.573
103921  N   2021-07-16 12:45:35.577
103921  N   2021-07-16 12:45:35.580
103921  A   2021-07-19 22:00:05.807
103921  A   2021-07-19 22:00:05.857
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:23.817
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:23.827
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:23.830
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.640
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.653
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.663
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.667
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.673
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.677
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.683
103917  N   2021-07-21 08:38:36.687
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.113
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.120
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.127
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.130
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.137
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.143
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.150
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.153
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.160
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.163
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.170
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.173
103917  M   2021-07-21 08:39:00.180
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.613
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.617
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.623
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.630
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.633
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.637
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.643
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.647
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.650
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.657
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.657
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.660
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.667
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.667
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.673
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.677
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.683
103917  A   2021-07-21 08:39:06.690
```

I made up two random 6 digit ID #'s and placed them in the table and produced the results (sorted by EventDateTime column)

I need to know when the status changes from 'N' to anything else for a specific ID.

I am hoping to produce a new table which contains a subset of ID numbers and EventType and the EventDateTime which meets the conditions.

Comment: 1/3/2020 Is that March 1st or January 3rd?

Comment: Are these the entire five rows in your database? When an event code changes, is that one one record just updated? Do you have a unique id that represents a specific event?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It's different rows. The rows don't need to be consecutive. The only rule is that it must start with 'N' and we must show a table with every eventcode after it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show a larger dataset. So far this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Did you try the answer below?

Comment: i did but was getting SYNTAX errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEAD()` and `LAG()` to peek at the next and previous rows respectively. Using these functions you can write:

```
select
  date, time, eventcode
from (
  select *,
    lead(eventcode) over(order by date) as next_code,
    lag(eventcode) over(order by date) as prev_code
  from events
  where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-06'
) x
where eventcode = 'N' and next_code <> 'N'
   or eventcode <> 'N' and prev_code = 'N'
```

Result:

```
 date        time      eventcode 
 ----------- --------- --------- 
 2020-01-02  08:00:00  N         
 2020-01-03  09:00:00  S
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pkcR4cc8ScJiWg9rHD3zG/0).

Comment: I am getting SYNTAX errors.
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I tried converting the string to a date by CONVERT(DATE, '2021-07-10')

Comment: @softwareisfun Maybe your data is in a different format. The query runs well according to the fiddle.